# WiFi keeps dissappearing

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, drivers

I have an HP Pavilion dv4-4065la. I've been using ubuntu 14.04 since last year (before I was using Windows...so yeah, I know nothing about linux) and nothing bad happened before, but some days ago the wifi started freezing, I mean, it was ok but suddenly when I tried to open a website it was impossible.

So I tried restarting the network-manager service but whenever I did that, the computer started getting slow and when the service restarted the Wlan0 was gone and no only that, it seemed that the device wasn't even connected... **lspci** didn't show anything about the wireless device untill I reboot the computer... that happens ALWAYS. I used the **iwconfig** and just shows **eth0** and **lo** devices. Also in the top nav bar shows something like this ... nothing about Wireless.

Getting mad I decided to reinstall Ubuntu ... 5 times with no results. It keeps freezing and disappearing. I've looked through the hole Internet but i can't find any solution. Most of the posts are for Broadcom devices, but I have an **Intel Centrino Wireless-N 1030**.

*********** uname -a

> Linux lios 3.16.0-30-generic #40~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 15
>   17:43:14 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

I installed also 3.16.0.31-generic yesterday I think, I've done a lot of things and then when I see nothing working, I reinstall the OS from USB using UNetbootin. When the problem started I had 14.04.1 (or at least I didn't know when upgraded to 14.04.2), now I have 14.04.2.

I've tried these things:

- Reinstalled Ubuntu
- Restarted network-manager service
- Downloaded the driver from Intel Driver for linux and copied to
  /lib/firmware, the    file is "iwlwifi-6000g2b-6.ucode" but I don't
  know if that is the correct way to install the driver

And executed these commands:

```
    echo "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
    sudo modprobe -rfv iwlwifi
    sudo modprobe -v iwlwifi
```

Also:

```
    sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
    sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source
    sudo modprobe wl
```

I think I've done more than that but I don't remember, I'm getting frustrated since this doesn't happen like each 30 minutes or so... I can use the Wifi perfectly sometimes for hours or a hole day and suddenly BUM!! the issue comes back and... well you know the story...

---- So at the middle of doing this the Wifi freezed again, so this is what some commands show BEFORE doing the network-manager restart:

***** lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net

> **01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino
>   Wireless-N 1030 [Rainbow Peak] [8086:008b] (rev ff)   Kernel driver in
>   use: iwlwifi**
>
> 02:00.0 System peripheral [0880]: JMicron Technology Corp. SD/MMC Host
>   Controller [197b:2392] (rev 30)
>
> 08:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros AR8151 v2.0
>   Gigabit Ethernet [1969:1083] (rev c0)     Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard
>   Company Device [103c:3585]    Kernel driver in use: atl1c

***** iwconfig

> eth0      no wireless extensions.
>
> wlan0     IEEE 802.11bg  ESSID:off/any
>             Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=15 dBm
>             Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
>             Power Management:off
>
> lo        no wireless extensions.

And then AFTER restarting the service, my wireless device used to dissappear. But this time it keeps showing the device but still can't use the wifi. If I open the connections pannel at the top-right it just gives me options for the wired connection, and shows nothing for wireless. I even tried to execute the command **sudo ifconfig wlan0 up** but I get a timeout error.

> sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
>
> SIOCSIFFLAGS: Expiró el tiempo de conexión (something like, connection time expired).

Then I plugged my ethernet and got this message:

> (4) Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote
>   application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy
>   blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network
>   connection was broken.

So I had to reboot my computer and then both wired and wireless connection reappeared like laughing on me. And I'm sure that wireless will break again, so I would really appreciate any ideas on how to fix this problem, and if my grammar is bad and you don't understand some parts I apologize, I don't speak English as native language.

Comment: Hate it when dem wifis just vanish out of thin air!

Comment: Yeah me too :c 
And I have really no idea on how to fix it.